# How to simultaneously create both 'web' and 'node' versions of a bundle with Webpack?

Tags: javascript, bundling-and-minification, browserify, webpack

Is there a way to create both 'web' and 'node' versions of a bundle with one go by using Webpack or Browserify? The 'web' version of the bundle will be used on a client, and 'node' version of the same bundle will be used on the server for pre-rendering ("[isomorphic](http://nerds.airbnb.com/isomorphic-javascript-future-web-apps/)" web application).

Comment: Do you actually mean bundling or do you just want to use your module in the browser? I typically don't use Browserify unless I need to port 3rd party software. I write my js files to work in both environments from the start

Comment: @slebetman, I'm using JSX in my JavaScript, also I'm bundling CSS and images.. So, it's not so easy to make it work in a browser without using Browserify or Webpack.

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way is probably just to create two configs, one with `target: "node"` and the other `target: "web"` in the configuration, and run them both like `$ webpack && webpack --config webpack.config.web.js`

Answer (score 1):

You can create multiple config objects in `webpack.config.js` file:

```
const config1 = {
  target: 'web',
  ...
}
const config2 = {
  target: 'node',
  ...
}

export default [config1, config2]
```