# How to not bundle node_modules, but use them normally in node.js?

Tags: node.js, bundling-and-minification, webpack

## Architecture

I would like to share code between client and server side. I have defined aliases in the webpack config:

```
resolve: {
    // Absolute paths: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/109
    alias: {
        server : absPath('/src/server/'),
        app    : absPath('/src/app/'),
        client : absPath('/src/client/'),
    }
},
```

## Problem

Now on the server side I need to include webpack in order to recognize the correct paths when I require a file. For example

```
require('app/somefile.js')
```

will fail in pure node.js because can't find the app folder.

## What I need (read the What I need updated section)

I need to be able to use the webpack aliases. I was thinking about making a bundle of all the server part without any file from node_modules. In this way when the server starts it will use node_modules from the node_modules folder instead of a minified js file (Why? 1st: it doesn't work. 2nd: is bad, because node_modules are compiled based on platform. So I don't want my win files to go on a unix server).

Output:

- Compiled `server.js` file without any node_modules included.
- Let the `server.js` to use node_modules;

## What I need updated

As I've noticed in https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/135 making a bundled server.js will mess up with all the io operation file paths.

A better idea would be to leave node.js server files as they are, but replace the `require` method provided with a custom webpack `require` which takes in account configurations such as aliases (others?)... Can be done how require.js has done to run on node.js server.

## What I've tried

By adding this plugin in webpack

```
 new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin(/* chunkName= */"ignore", /* filename= */"server.bundle.js")
```

Entries:

```
entry: {
    client: "./src/client/index.js",
    server: "./src/server/index.js",
    ignore: ['the_only_node_module'] // But I need to do that for every node_module
},
```

It will create a file server.js which only contains my server code. Then creates a server.bundle.js which is not used. But the problem is that webpack includes the `webpackJsonp` function in the `server.bundle.js` file. Therefore both the client and server will not work.

It should be a way to just disable node_modules on one entry.

## What I've tried # 2

I've managed to exclude the path, but requires doesn't work because are already minified. So the source looks like `require(3)` instead of `require('my-module')`. Each require string has been converted to an integer so it doesn't work.

In order to work I also need to patch the require function that webpack exports to add the node.js native require function (this is easy manually, but should be done automatically).

## What I've tried # 3

In the webpack configuration:

```
{target: "node"}
```

This only adds an `exports` variable (not sure about what else it does because I've diffed the output).

## What I've tried # 4 (almost there)

Using

```
require.ensure('my_module')
```

and then replacing all occurrences of `r(2).ensure` with require. I don't know if the `r(2)` part is always the same and because of this might not be automated.

## Solved

Thanks to [ColCh](https://github.com/ColCh) for enlighten me on how to do [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/603).

```
require = require('enhanced-require')(module, require('../../webpack.config'));
```

By changing the `require` method in node.js it will make node.js to pass all requires trough the webpack `require` function which allow us to use aliases and other gifts! Thanks ColCh!

## Related

- https://www.bountysource.com/issues/1660629-what-s-the-right-way-to-use-webpack-specific-functionality-in-node-js
- https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/135
- http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#target
- https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/458
- [How to simultaneously create both 'web' and 'node' versions of a bundle with Webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26063480/how-to-simultaneously-create-both-web-and-node-versions-of-a-bundle-with-web)
- http://nerds.airbnb.com/isomorphic-javascript-future-web-apps/

Thanks

Comment: what should be in the parameter "module"? Is that the module you want to require?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to [ColCh](https://github.com/ColCh) for enlighten me on how to do [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/603).

```
require = require('enhanced-require')(module, require('../../webpack.config'));
```

By changing the `require` method in node.js it will make node.js to pass all requires trough the webpack `require` function which allow us to use aliases and other gifts! Thanks ColCh!

Answer (score 0):

My solution was:

```
{
    // make sure that webpack will externalize
    // modules using Node's module API (CommonJS 2)
    output: { ...output, libraryTarget: 'commonjs2' },

    // externalize all require() calls to non-relative modules.
    // Unless you do something funky, every time you import a module
    // from node_modules, it should match the regex below
    externals: /^[a-z0-9-]/,

    // Optional: use this if you want to be able to require() the
    // server bundles from Node.js later
    target: 'node'
}
```

Comment: Lastly, you might want to disable pollyfills and mocks that webpack provides to your server bundle: https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#node